# Problem to set MySQL password and open it

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

> Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.".

I installed Ubuntu, and I tried to install MySQL. I have this problem, I could not set the password for the root user, I removed it from the system.

I installed it again, and now I have this problem. These are the steps that I followed so far:

1. sudo service mysql status ○ mysql.service Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit mysql.service is masked.) Active: inactive (dead)
2. sudo systemctl start mysql Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service is masked.
3. systemctl unmask mysql.service Removed /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.
4. service mysql start Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and 'journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.

Comment: Can you read that?

Comment: Did you look at the things the error message asked you to look at? If not do so and show us what they contain if the issue does not become clear to you